# What is the best practice to have KeyValue DTO for diffrent usage

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What is the best practice if you want to have two KeyValue DTOs with different type for the Key, which sometimes is type of 'int' and sometimes is 'string' .
is it better to have tow DTO like these:

```
public class KeyValueDto
    {
        public int Key { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }

public class KeyValueDto
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }
```

OR have one DTO:

```
public class KeyValueDto
    {
        public object Key { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }
```

consider the cost of casting operation where ever using DTO?

Comment: What abut a generic `KeyValueDto<T>`?

Comment: That would be good, but it seems where ever I want to use it, I have to Declare the type of both key and value. @KlausGütter

Comment: Isn't possible to convert key of type int to string? On both server and client-side, if the conversion failed, it means the key had been string, otherwise, it'd been an int.

Comment: I tend to think that best practice when using an OO language is to avoid using `object`. Typically my DTOs are all specifically typed for the job they do. What application do you have that mandates passing data in the most generic way possible?

Comment: @A.Nadjar it is possible, but I want to avoid doing convert or cast ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var a= new KeyValueDto<int>(){
            Key = 1,
            Value = "ali"
        };

        var b = new KeyValueDto<string>{
            Key = "1",
            Value = "ali1"
        };

    }

    public class KeyValueDto<T>
    {
        public T Key { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }


}
```